# How do I convert multiple columns into one from Binary data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My data has 3 surveys per year (for 10 years) where 1 represents presence and 0s present absence. The subset looks like this

```r
x <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
                 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
               .Dim = c(4L, 3L, 4L))
```

I want to collapse these three columns into one in a way that every row that has 1 in any survey, shows 1 in the final otherwise shows 0.

Comment: What do the dimensions of your array represent? ie, is it [subject, survey, year], or [year, survey, subject]…?

Comment: Provide reproducible data `dput(mydata)`. Solution would something like `as.integer(rowSums(x)>0)`

Comment: @zephryl it is [site, survey, year]

Comment: Please have a look at the [*How to make a great R reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) discussion in order to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `max`

```
apply(x, c(1, 3), FUN = max)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Yes, that is much better!

Answer (score 2):

Collapse the second dimension of the array with `apply`:

```r
apply(x, c(1L, 3L), function(y) as.integer(any(as.logical(y))))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    1    1    1    1
## [3,]    0    1    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    1    1
```

The result is a `[site, year]` matrix.